# AJAX download not working

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a valid url which I am trying to download using [ajax](/questions/tagged/ajax).

What's wrong with the following code?

```
url = "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/analyst-3206a.appspot.com/o/research_reports%2FNt7cXdWHFlQuwRcy8wo4B49VNeD3%2Fa?alt=media&token=5521f889-2737-4433-a279-f04999cdff22"

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.responseType = 'blob';
xhr.onload = function(event) {
  var blob = xhr.response;
};
xhr.open('GET', url);
xhr.send();
```

Comment: This code is nothing wrong. What do you mean 'not working'?

Comment: I mean not downloading, it just silently runs to completion

Comment: Your file is a `PNG` format. See its header: https://imgur.com/a/ZapGY.

Comment: yes it is. so ? how does format matter ?

Answer (score 2):

you have to put [createObjectURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL)

```js
url = "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/analyst-3206a.appspot.com/o/research_reports%2FNt7cXdWHFlQuwRcy8wo4B49VNeD3%2Fa?alt=media&token=5521f889-2737-4433-a279-f04999cdff22"
var a = document.getElementById("a");
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.responseType = 'blob';
  xhr.onload = function (event) {
    var blob = xhr.response;

    var a = document.createElement("a"),
        url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    document.body.appendChild(a);
        a.href = url;
        a.download = "fileName." + blob.type;
        a.click();
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);

  };
  xhr.open('GET', url);
  xhr.send();
```

Comment: It's downloading a pdf which is corrupt. The url I gave is an image.

Comment: You can change to: `a.download = "fileName.png";`. Setting the extension. By default `blob.type` is returning `pdf`...